# I am new to JavaScript. please help me for javascript validation

Tags: javascript

I need to put a validation in textarea that text must start with a number and then a '\' with the help of regular expression e.g '5\' in javascript can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add a [mcve] detailing the code you have tried. Explain why it did not work for you and what the expected results are.

Answer (score -1):

You need to hook up a user event (such as blur, a field dropping input focus) to a function that validates the content to your regex.

Example with jQuery:

```
$(".text-field").on("blur", function () {
    var test = /^\d/\/.test($(this).value());
    if (!test) {
        alert("invalid text");
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't answer bad questions.  It just encourages them to ask more.

Comment: It is not about specifics. It was to at least get started with the concepts of javascript and how to add it to your site. I see your point, but why the down-vote for explaining some concepts?